# Chinese national, UK residency, supported by partner - how to to get a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, residency, chinese-citizens

I've been reading through various posts here on foreign spouse/UK residency, Schengen visa application - but my situation is a little different so I'm hoping someone can help clarify.

I'm a UK national, having lived with a Chinese national for 4 years in Scotland. She has permanent residency from a previous marriage. She has just finished her studies, graduates 2018, therefore not working in the UK.

We wish to travel to Paris in January. I'm assuming I need to prove we live together in the UK. I support us, and we will return to the UK.

Is this correct? I can't seem to find information relating to our cohabiting situation, and I'm thinking an agency may help me resolve this, or is this something I can resolve through TLScontact?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not married and simply want to visit the Schengen area as a tourist, a far simpler option would be to go ahead and apply for a regular tourist visa as a non-EU citizen. Being a permanent resident of the UK means your partner's chances of being refused are effectively nill, so you being an EU citizen yourself won't change much given the circumstances.

Source: statistics of Schengen visa applications in the UK.